# difficulty with CORS on an "alternate" domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an Amazon CloudFront setup that points to an S3 bucket as a CDN. I also have an alternate domain name (not on Route53) that points to this CloudFront.

I kept having trouble getting scripts to pull through the CDN when using the alternate domain name - but if I use the native one from the CloudFront control panel, it works.

Is there something special I need to do other than just set the domain name CNAME to point to the amazon CloudFront address for CORS to work?

Comment: Such as [telling CloudFront about the name you're pointing to it](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)?

Comment: I added the URL of the domain in the place it asked me to when setting up Cloud Front. Is there somewhere else it needs to be set?

Comment: Can you download directly from CloudFront using the alternate hostname?  Is the problem you're having isolated only to cross-origin requests?  Have you tried simulating a cross-origin request using `curl`?

Comment: And then it just started working right.. for no clear reason. Out of nowhere.

Comment: Yes, I can download from cloudfront directly.

Comment: Best guess: CloudFront had cached some responses from requests you sent before you had everything set the way you needed it.  The `Age:` response header will tell you how long a particular response has been cached.

Comment: Nevermind. It worked because I rebooted and the `--disable-web-security` flag I put on chrome kicked in.

Comment: Alright, sorry. To answer you. Yes, I can access the files with both the amazon URL, and my custom domain name.

Comment: Aha! I think I fixed it. There was a little nugget setting that I needed to enable to allow the headers in some kind of whitelist. It wasn't even discussed in amazon's docs.

Comment: Maybe here? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-cors

Comment: Yes, it is in there. I must not have read it all closely enough. Would you please post this as the answer so I may award credit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111430/discussion-between-michael-sqlbot-and-ciel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important part of correctly caching web requests is to ensure that a response to be served from the cache is "correct," in the sense if whether it will match the response generated by the origin, for the same request.

This isn't as simple as it sounds, since responses can vary based on the content if certain request headers.

CloudFront adopts a conservative and safe approach, by stripping most request headers as it forwards requests to the origin server -- if the server can't see the header, it can't use the header to vary its response.

In the case of CORS, it's critical for the origin server to see the `Origin:`, `Access-Control-Request-Headers:`, and `Access-Control-Request-Method:` headers so it can respond accordingly.

But forwarding unnecessary headers to the origin server causes inefficient caching, since the cached response will only be served against identical future requests, identical including the forwarded headers.

So the three CORS request headers must be "whitelisted" in the CloudFront cache behavior, so that they will be forwarded to the origin server (in this case, S3).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-cors

Comment: Thank you for the patience with me. It is true that the problems stemmed from my own inadequacies and failure to fully read the documentation _very, very thoroughly_.